Regression with a constant sharing a coefficient with an independent variable
I have an equation which I’m trying to estimate but I’m not sure what the effects would be if any.
Y = b0 + b1 * p + b1 * X + e

Where,
Y is the dependent
b0 is the intercept
X is an independent variable
b1 is the coefficient for X
e is the error
p is a constant value or 0, p = 0 for 70% of obs, for the other 30% the obs have a constant value they all share.

Edit: I can’t merge p with X. It’s part of the nature of the data.  Although adding p to X simplifies estimation there won’t be an interpretation available to the model.
I need p, not to have its own coefficient as it must share the coefficient of X, b1.
I’m hoping that because the variable p is either a constant or 0 that it won’t have any effect on b1 the coefficient for X.
Am I right in assuming p won’t have an effect because it’s constant or 0? Can I simplify b1*p into some sort of indicator variable that doesn’t carry its own coefficient?
Not sure how to solve this

Could you explain what you mean by "70/30% split"?

Some of the observations have a constant value p associated with them. Other observations don’t have p, so p is 0 for some observations about 70% while the rest do have p.

Then $p$ is just another regressor variable and your model is $Y=b_0 + b_1(p+X)+e,$ as explained by Noah.  I don't understand your problem about "wouldn't be interpretable," because this is exactly the model you have specified, so nothing changes in the interpretation.

p and X don’t share an additive relationship it’s more multiplicative than anything else so I can’t just add the two numbers. The relationship between p and X depends on the constant value itself so it’s sort of like an indicator type variable.

Part of the reason for this is because it’s related to the laplace distribution which I understood as a combination of distributions. I may be wrong though.

If you "can't just add the two numbers," then you haven't described your model correctly.  You have stipulated, explicitly, an additive relationship.  The contradiction in denying that leaves us wondering what you are trying to ask.  Rather than describing it abstractly, consider explaining the actual problem.

Problem is the data is a mixture of real and imaginary numbers. I did some transformations to deal with it but I’m not sure if it’s doable analysis wise. that said I can interpret this model assuming it can be estimated.

Are you saying the values are complex numbers (which is not a complication at all) or are you trying to say something else?  Your comments leave a strong sense that you have a problem that is very different from the one you have attempted to express abstractly.

If you replace X with Xp = X + p, then you can run a standard regression of Y on Xp to get b1. This assumes p is observed in your dataset.
This will change the value of b1 compared to if you were to omit p entirely because Xp is a new variable with values that differ from X.

Hi thx for the response but I can’t merge the two together mostly because the resulting model and coefficients wouldn’t be interpretable according to relevant theory and the data itself. I added an edit to the question to clarify my issue.

@VarianceOfOne What I described is a method for estimating b1 that has the qualities you desire; it does not change the interpretation of the model at all. It's a computational trick, not a change in the substantive nature of the model. The interpretation of the coefficients comes from the model you initially described, not the model that is used to estimate the parameters. So you absolutely can and should use this method to estimate b1; it does exactly what you want with no change to interpretation.

What if p was imaginary?

@VarianceOfOne You would need to explain what you mean.
